# Get DOM elements to hide an element from afterRender event in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-experience, javascript-controller, dom

I am trying to access Page related DOM elements which are not part of aura component. I am trying to access elements with the help of afterRender. I am able to get the element but i can see only proxy elements{}. can anyone help me to access my values from proxy object. I want to get any 1 element in the list (li) and hide that element from the DOM.

```
afterRender: function (component, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();
    var timerId = window.setInterval(function() {
        var buttonsGroupElement = document.querySelectorAll("ul.branding-actions.slds-button-group.slds-m-left--xx-small.oneActionsRibbon.forceActionsContainer>li");
        console.log('buttonsGroupElement-- ',buttonsGroupElement); // I AM GETTING PROXY HERE
        console.log('buttonsGroupElement[0]-- ',buttonsGroupElement[0]); // is always undefined.
        Object.keys(buttonsGroupElement).forEach(key => console.log('ELEMENT TO ACCESS',buttonsGroupElement[key]));     // this line is breaking . no log is printing       
    }, 1000);
},
```

[image: Console]

Comment: The proxy is just a wrapper for the data. Since you're querying stuff you "own", you shouldn't have any problems accessing any individual element. What problem are you having specifically? Where does your code fail?

Comment: @sfdcfox buttonsGroupElement[0] is always undefined.